# Istio proxy log format

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

The Istio documentation provides a sample `istio-proxy` log, as below:

```
[2019-03-06T09:31:27.354Z] "GET /status/418 HTTP/1.1" 418 - "-" 0 135 11 10 "-" "curl/7.60.0" "d209e46f-9ed5-9b61-bbdd-43e22662702a" "httpbin:8000" "172.30.146.73:80" outbound|8000||httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local - 172.21.13.94:8000 172.30.146.82:60290 -
```

The linked Envoy documentation mentions that for log format is as follow:

```
[%START_TIME%] "%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%"
%RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION%
%RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% "%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%" "%REQ(USER-AGENT)%"
"%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%" "%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%" "%UPSTREAM_HOST%"\n
```

example from Envoy:

```
[2016-04-15T20:17:00.310Z] "POST /api/v1/locations HTTP/2" 204 - 154 0 226 100 "10.0.35.28"
"nsq2http" "cc21d9b0-cf5c-432b-8c7e-98aeb7988cd2" "locations" "tcp://10.0.2.1:80"
```

This format is different than the one used by `istio-proxy`.

The documentation seems out of sync with the Envoy documentation as the provided sample log cannot be mapped to the Envoy default logged format. What is the log format here? What is being logged?

Comment: What is your istio version? Have You seen that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867545/what-is-istio-proxy-access-log-mean) on stackoverlow? There are few things about logs. I think Joh Zheng answer matches with your "example from envoy". Let me know if that's the answer you're looking for.

Comment: That seems to answer my question, thanks